# Mount NTFS (read/write capability) filesystem on RHEL 5 (2.6.8-18.el5)

Tags: linux, ntfs, rhel5

I'm using RHEL 5.0 with the kernel 2.6.8-18.el5. I want to mount my external hard disk drive with the NTFS file system. I cannot mount it because it doesn't support NTFS file system. Error msg: mount: unknown 'ntfs' file system.

Can anyone tell me to mount this hard disk?

Regards,

Sarith

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [NTFS-3g](http://www.ntfs-3g.org/) driver:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows
```

I'm not sure if there's a RHEL package available for it in YUM.

Comment: I should clarify what I mean regarding YUM. If you're using YUM to install packages and you're using only the RHN repo's (to maintain a support agreement) - I'm not sure that the packages are available. You will of course be able to get them from DAG or RPMFORGE etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the NTFS utils package installed? I can't tell you the exact name of the package, but I'm sure someone will comment. Linux does support NTFS filesystems. You can check if your system will support it by running:

```
# modprobe ntfs
# grep ntfs /proc/filesystems
    ntfs
#
```

If you get no output, your kernel does not support NTFS. If it does, then you need to install the ntfs utils package.

Answer (score 1):

RHEL5 does not come with either a native or a fuse ntfs driver. If you want to do this, you will have to install both fuse and ntfs3g from DAG (where I [know](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/fuse-ntfs-3g/) they exist)

Then do as Karolis T. says to mount the disk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have NTFS-3G filesystem support if you want to write to your NTFS disk.

Try searching for "ntfs-3g" in yum package manager and install fuse (file system in userspace implementation) and the ntfs-3g itself.

You can then proceed to mount it with:

```
# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/device /mnt/mountpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.irwan.name/?p=36
download the FUSE and ntfs module from here