# Mount a ntfs external hard disk to Centos i386

Tags: mount

I've Centos installed on a 32 bit system

Now I want to mount a external HDD of NTFS file system. I've read the article [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/27109/mount-ntfs-read-write-capability-filesystem-on-rhel-5-2-6-8-18-el5) and have installed fuse & ntfs-3g with the instructions [here](http://blog.irwan.name/?p=36). I've installed the following libraries:

- fuse-2.7.4-8_12.el5.i386.rpm
- fuse-ntfs-3g-2009.11.14-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
- fuse-libs-2.7.4-8_12.el5.i386.rpm
- fuse-kmdl-2.6.18-238.el5xen-2.7.4-8_12.el5.x86_64.rpm

Now I want to continue to mount using this command

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/device /mnt/mountpoint
```

but I don't know the device name or watsoeva. the example given on the terminal is:

```
ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows
```

But I don't quite get it. How can I find out my device name?

**Update**

I actually got this back from the result:

```
  SCSI device sda: 625142448 512-byte hdwr sectors (320073 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: Mode Sense: 38 00 00 00
sda: assuming drive cache: write through
SCSI device sda: 625142448 512-byte hdwr sectors (320073 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: Mode Sense: 38 00 00 00
sda: assuming drive cache: write through
 sda: sda1
sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi disk sda
SCSI device sdb: 3940479 512-byte hdwr sectors (2018 MB)
sdb: Write Protect is off
sdb: Mode Sense: 45 00 00 08
sdb: assuming drive cache: write through
SCSI device sdb: 3940479 512-byte hdwr sectors (2018 MB)
sdb: Write Protect is off
sdb: Mode Sense: 45 00 00 08
sdb: assuming drive cache: write through
 sdb: sdb1
sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi removable disk sdb
sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi removable disk sdc
sd 3:0:0:1: Attached scsi removable disk sdd
sd 3:0:0:2: Attached scsi removable disk sde
sd 3:0:0:3: Attached scsi removable disk sdf
sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
sd 3:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
sd 3:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
sd 3:0:0:3: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
SELinux: initialized (dev sdb1, type vfat), uses genfs_contexts
```

So how should I modify my `mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/device /mnt/mountpoint`

What is /mnt/mountpoint? Do I define that?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the size of your disk, you can run 'dmesg | grep sd', and look for the disk in the output that matches the size of the disk you are useing (the ntfs disk). From there the sdX1, sdX2, sdX3 would be the partitions to be mounted in /dev, where X is the disk label

Comment: Yup, checking dmesg output after you plug in the disk is the simplest way to find the disk name.

Comment: hi from your command, is it only displaying external hdd items??

Comment: it is displaying all serial drive hardware change info, so any usb or sata drives (internal or external)

Answer (score 0):

To your second question: `/mnt/mountpoint` is a directory where your disk will be attached. This can be any directory you like: `/mnt/usbdisk`, `/home/me/hdd`, `/media/hdd` or anything else. But: this directory should exists, so you may need to create it before mounting anything to it.