# Trouble with mount NTFS partition in Xen server 7.0 (read/write access)

Tags: centos, mount, xenserver

The mount must be a read/write access.

I've tried mount a hard drive with ntfs partion with the following commands in Xen server 7.0 :

```
fdisk -l
```

Result

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *        2048   976769023   488383488    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Tried to mount NTFS

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /mnt/
```

Result

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs-3g'
```

PS.: I have based in this topic

[I've Centos installed on a 32 bit system](https://serverfault.com/questions/225469/mount-a-ntfs-external-hard-disk-to-centos-i386)

Comment: Did you install the ntfs-3g package? You should also first create a mountpoint under /mnt and point to that in your mount command

Comment: I tried right now and works fine, thanks... @inaki

Comment: That's right way to do this?
for me no problem, but there are a another way?

Comment: Normally that's the way afaik.

Comment: That's the normal approach afaik.